# Scaling on orientation change AndEngine livewallpaper extension

Tags: android, andengine, screen-orientation, live-wallpaper

Hi I Am trying to create a LiveWallpaper with AndEngine and the AndEngine LWP extension. Now I have the following test image: [image: Test background]

My Wallpaper is initalized with a width and height of 1024x600. When the orientation changes from portrait to landscape I would like the camera to only rotate 90 degrees. So that I can see the kinda orange color on the sides. The green blocks should only be visible in portrait mode. At the moment the camera keeps its rotation and scales the scene to fit the width of the landscape size. I am using the AndEngine LiveWallpaper Example as shown on their website. Can someone help me out with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my problem by adding the following line in the onSurfaceChanged function:

```
    camera.set(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
```

Where the width and hight depends on the orientation.